# Getting each column in a string in webservice and display it in textview in android

Tags: java, android, sql, web-services, android-studio

i have this webservice:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string findUserNameById(int Id)
    {
        return getStudent(Id);

    }

    public String getStudent(int id)
    {

        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = Class1.ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.tblUser where Id=" + id + "";
        SqlDataReader sdr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();
        String address = null;
        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            address = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            address += "," + sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
            address += "," + sdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        }

        conn.Close();
        return address;


    }
```

which retrieve row values like this: Id, name, grade. and im calling this webservice from android application:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private Handler mHandler= new Handler();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
public void getName(View v){

    String inputId =editText.getText().toString();
    //String[] params= new String[]{"10.0.2.2",inputId};
    String[] params= new String[]{"192.168.1.17:90",inputId};
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);

}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    public String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/findUserNameById";
    public String OPERATION_NAME ="findUserNameById";
    public String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org/";
    public String SOAP_ADDRESS;
    private SoapObject request;
    private HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop;
    Object response= null;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SOAP_ADDRESS="http://"+params[0]+"/myWebService.asmx";
        request= new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("Id");
        pi.setValue(Integer.parseInt(params[1]));
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        pi= new PropertyInfo();

        envelop= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelop.dotNet=true;
        envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        httpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        try{
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelop);
            response=envelop.getResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            response=e.getMessage();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

what I want is, to view each column in text view. how to do this in the webservice and in the java code? I don't want it to be in single string all data, I want id in string, name in other string and so on. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON response from the web service and parse the JSON in android

Since android and your webserver is written in JAVA you can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to help u in object to json and vise versa conversion

**Edit 1:**
Here is a sample [tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/17/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) to get started

Comment: Can you refer to a tutorial please?

Comment: Edited the answer do check it